# Why does variable substitution work in this awk one-liner?

Tags: bash, shell, awk

The Internet says that to use a shell variable in Awk, you can either double-quote the Awk program (which is a bad idea), or use Awk's variable-passing mechanism (which is the correct approach).

Why then do I get this?

```
$ export name=Andrew
$ echo 'hello' | awk '{system("echo ${name}, " $1)}'
Andrew, hello
```

Is it because Awk spawns a shell to execute the `system` command, the variable substitution is interpreted by that shell rather than by Awk, and that shell, being a sub-shell of the shell that launched Awk, inherits its shell variables?

Comment: Yes, that is why.  Because the `name` variable is marked for export in the parent shell, `awk` both receives it in its own environment (not as an `awk` variable) and passes it on in the environment of any child process it spawns.

Comment: @anubhava I don't really want to just `echo`. I want to pipe input from rsync and I don't just want to echo it, I want to `svn delete` it.

Comment: Can you clarify then what really is your question.

Comment: Whatever document you have that suggests double-quoting the awk script would be a reasonable approach is wrong, get rid of it. See http://cfajohnson.com/shell/cus-faq-2.html#Q24 for how to really pass the value of shell variables to awk script.

Comment: @EdMorton no no, I only read that it was _possible_. Edited question.

Comment: Ah, I see. btw the correct syntax for your call to system() would be `system("echo "\"${name}\", \"" $1 "\"")` otherwise you are calling `echo` on an unquoted (and so expanded) shell variable but it's very rare that you'd want to do that anyway - if you're considering doing it then post a question here as there's probably a better alternative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`awk` passes the literal string `echo ${name}, hello` to the system shell to process. Because you exported `name` prior to calling `awk`, `name=Andrew` appears in `awk`'s environment, and `awk` passes it on to the system shell in turn. The shell then is able to expand `${name}` to Andrew as a result.

Comment: so `awk`'s `system()` command creates a sub-shell from the current one?

Comment: @fedorqui: Yes it definitely does that.

Comment: Thanks. So it's the `export` that makes it work. TBH I had forgotten what was the reason for always declaring variables with `export xyz=`. Now I will remember. :)

Comment: No, do NOT always declare variables that way as you are cluttering up the global name space and will encounter problems with clashes in your environment. By convention any exported variable should have an all-upper-case name, and ONLY do it for variables that you specifically NEED to be exported.

Comment: Expressed myself badly. I was thinking in the context of "in an interactive shell and setting some value needed by the command I'm about to launch" which was implicit for me because for a long time that was the only reason I ever set variables. In that context, "always" is right, right?